# How to add country flag in options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to add country flag using options_for_select method but no success. Can someone help?

I tried a couple of options already(example below), none of them works properly.

```
options_for_select(ISO3166::Country.all.map { |country| [country.name, country.alpha2, { 'class' => "flag-icon flag-icon-us"}] }.sort_by { |country| country.first }, countries)
```

Comment: The code you have does this for me:
<option class="flag-icon flag-icon-us" value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
Are you hoping for something else?

Comment: Yeah that looks correct but somehow the flag icon doesn't show up in my application..

Comment: Did you remember to add the flag-icon CSS to your layout template?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this instead?

```
options_for_select(ISO3166::Country.all.map { |country| [country.name, country.alpha2, country.emoji_flag] }.sort_by { |country| country.first }, countries)
```